# Bluebird: Run sequence of promise-returning functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, bluebird

What is the most concise way to run a dynamically generated sequence of functions, where each function returns a Promise which must be resolved before the next should run?

For example:

```
// Assume the following 'process' functions are generated elsewhere

function process_1 (input) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_1');
    });
}

function process_2 (input) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_2');
    });
}

function process_3 (input) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_3');
    });
}

// We can construct a sequence of these functions,
// but each one still needs to be 'configured' with a value
// before it can return it's promise.

var process = [process_1, process_2, process_3]
```

The collection methods available on Bluebirds `Promise` (eg `all`, `each` etc) seems to deal with collections of *values*, rather than collections of promise generating functions.

If I try and map or reduce the sequence into a sequence of promises rather than functions, then I lose the ability of passing the result of one promise into the next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [reduce](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) for this:

```
bluebird.reduce( [process_1, process_2, process_3], function ( input, next ) {                                                                                                                                     
    return next( input );
}, 'INPUT' ).then( function ( result ) { 
    console.log( result );
} );
```

Note: You're also missing an input argument for `process_2` and `process_3` that must be added for this to work.

```
function process_1 (input) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_1');
    });
}

function process_2 ( input ) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_2');
    });
}

function process_3 ( input ) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(input + '_3');
    });
}

bluebird.reduce( [process_1, process_2, process_3], function ( input, next ) {
    return next( input );                                                                                                                                                                                          
}, 'INPUT' ).then( function ( result ) {
    console.log( result );
} );

// INPUT_1_2_3
```

Comment: Thanks, I spotted the missing arguments as you were writing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative non-bluebird-specific way:

```
var p = arrayOfFns.reduce((p, c) => p.then(c), Promise.resolve('INPUT'));
p.then(console.log);
```